# How does RPM determine whether a symbol is needed and present?

Tags: rpm

When I install a rpm package, it sometimes report messages like this:

```
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by xxx.rpm
```

I'm wondering how RPM figures that out, and how can I add my own checkpoints on symbols.

It seems to be a fully automatic process during rpmbuild, but I'm not sure about that.

Does anyone know?

Comment: What do you mean by "add my own checkpoints on symbols"? Add where?

Comment: rpm "only" has to run `ldd` on the shared objects/executables to determine this.  That's built into the tool. There are other types of dependencies (such as for Perl scripts), but again, little that you can control in the spec file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new rpm is built, the `rpmbuild` command checks by default [all the dependencies](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/more_dependencies.html#automatic-dependencies) of the binaries that belong to this rpm (using a [dependency generator](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/dependency_generators.html)). It usually has some helper script<sup>1</sup> such as [`find-requires`](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html)<sup>2</sup> that checks the dependencies of all the files in the rpms' `%files%` section:

```
$ echo /usr/bin/tree | /usr/lib/rpm/find-requires
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
```

Then it adds those requirements to the rpm metadata:

```
$ rpm --requires -q tree | grep libc
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
```

You can get the list of rpms that have this dependency:

```
rpm --whatrequires -q 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)'
```

And you can also check which package **provides** (or satisfies) this dependency:

```
$ rpm --whatprovides -q 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)'
glibc-2.22-114.22.1.x86_64
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Usually this helper script is defined in one of the macros of `rpmbuild`.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>This script utilizes another helper tool that extracts the requirements , for instance [`rpmdeps`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rpmdeps.8.html) or [`elfdeps`](https://github.com/lostutils/elfdeps):</sub>

```
$ /usr/lib/rpm/rpmdeps -R /usr/bin/tree 
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)

$ /usr/lib/rpm/elfdeps --requires /usr/bin/tree
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6()(64bit)
```